# MindSphere SDK V2 for Java - authorization fail

Tags: authorization, token, mindsphere

My code:

```
String token = request.getHeader("authorization"); // I was checked, token have value type Bearer.
MindsphereCredentials credentials = MindsphereCredentials.userTokenBuilder()
            .authorization(token)
            .build();
```

But my program returns an error at `.authorization`

**ERROR** get from

```sh
cf logs program_name --recent
```

> 2020-06-18T17:09:26.96+0900 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] tainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/].[dispatcher] SEVERE  Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/auth0/jwt/exceptions/JWTDecodeException] with root cause

I follow this link: [mindsphere-sdk-java-v2/sdkreadme_v2](https://developer.mindsphere.io/resources/mindsphere-sdk-java-v2/sdkreadme_v2.html)

Answer (score 0):

A `NoClassDefFoundError` exception usually suggests that you're missing a dependency.

This is not stated anywhere in the documentation, but it's not enough to just include the MindSphere SDK to your project alone; you also need some additional dependencies to make it work. Try adding the following to your Gradle/Maven build scripts:

```
org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.12
com.auth0:java-jwt:3.10.2
```

They're available in Maven Central.